# How to use the parsley.js pattern tag?

Tags: regex, validation, parsley.js

How do I add the `attr:data-parsley-pattern=""` tag correctly to a input?

I wrote this:

```
<input type="text" name="serialnr" id="serialnr" data-parsley-pattern="^[a-zA-Z]{4}[ -]?[a-zA-Z]{4}[ -]?[a-zA-Z]{4}[ -]?[a-zA-Z]{4}$">
```

But this does exactly nothing (No validation takes place at all while the other input are validated correctly). Do I have to add `data-parsley-required="true"`? (Which I did but that didn't help).
I tested the regex with https://www.debuggex.com/ so It shouldn't be a typo. What do I miss?

I call parsley only via data-attributes. Does that matter maybe?

Thank you.

Comment: All looks good, do you mind including the whole form (or at least the form tag and other inputs) or whipping up a quick JSFiddle?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your code seems to work perfectly here: http://jsfiddle.net/c2r4R/

What you need to know: Parsley validates only empty **required** fields. Your `data-parsley-pattern` directive is not applied if field is left empty. You'll need to add a `required` tag in order to throw an error if field is left empty, and throw another pattern error if field do not match your serial number pattern.

Best

Comment: Thanks I found the error, my cms form plugin stripped the whole regex tag :( but hardcoded it works.

Comment: Is there any solution to change the default message using parsley?