# Text box should not accept 0's using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to validate the textbox that should not contain all 0's or even just 1 zero, but it can contain any alphanumeric..

Condition is if we give just 0 or all 0's, it should not allow. Can we just check with the `val`?

Here is the code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#btnSave").click(function(){
    AlertSave();
  });
});

function AlertSave(){
  if($('#txt').val() == '0'){
    alert('should not be 0')
  }
}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/h4JXs/4865/)

Comment: You're probably better off using a regex than just checking the value.

Comment: You are checking if the entire value is '0' not whether or not it *contains* a '0'.  You could use regex or just do `$('#txt').val().IndexOf('0') > -1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if all characters are '0':

```
if ([].every.call($('#txt').val(), _ => _ === '0')){
      alert('should not be 0')
    }
```

Comment: super.. every.call will check all characters by keeping in the array?

Comment: It just treats the string like an array, passing each character to the compare function.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Parsley pattern tag with regex to validate your field. check out this [How to use the parsley.js pattern tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23473710/how-to-use-the-parsley-js-pattern-tag)

Answer (score 0):

Remove extra spaces, break lines, tabs

```
    function AlertSave() {
    var val = $('#txt').val().replace(/[\s\n\r]/g,"");
         if( val == 0 || val.indexOf("0") > -1){
          alert('should not be 0')
        }
    }
```